# An error occurred (InvalidParametersException) when calling the ProvisionProduct operation: A stack named AccountLaunch-Foo already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-service-catalog

I want to batch create accounts via a cloud formation stack as described in this blog:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/mt/how-to-automate-the-creation-of-multiple-accounts-in-aws-control-tower/

My last attempt failed (because the target organisation was not registered with control tower, I have since deleted the failed stack and registered the organization). Now I want to run it again but it fails. In the dynamoDB table I see under `Message`:

> An error occurred (InvalidParametersException) when calling the ProvisionProduct operation: A stack named AccountLaunch-Foo-51 already exists.

where Foo-51 is the account I want to create. The same message appears for all the other accounts in my batch.

Now I would like to delete this existing stack `AccountLaunch-Foo-51` but I cannot find it.
I've looked in cloudformation but I can only see the stacks used for the batch creation of accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The stacks can be found in the service catalog under `Provisioned Products`. Make sure the `Access filter` is set to `Account`. You can find and terminate `AccountLaunch-Foo-51` there.